# add progress bar for upload file

Tags: progress-bar, axios

I have a form to submit file,my html code is here:

```
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <button onclick="upload()">upload</button>
```

and I have axios code to upload,such as this code

```
  function upload() {
    var file = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
    var formdata = new FormData;
    formdata.append('file',file);
    const config = {
        onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
            var percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) 
             / progressEvent.total );
            console.log(percentCompleted)
        }
    };
    axios.post("/upload/test", formdata,  config,{
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
}
```

I can get percent of upload in console,But I don't know How I can show this in progress bar,Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 has actually a well supported progress tag. eg:

```
<progress max="100" value="80"></progress>
```

so, all you need to do is something along those lines:

```
onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
    var percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total );
    $('progress').attr('value', percentCompleted);
    console.log(percentCompleted)
}
```

Browser-Support is good:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=progress

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to find a way to update a state variable with the percent of upload (If you're using react), then use it as the value in the html progress tag

```
const [progressPercentage,setProgressPercentage] = usestate[0]
 function upload() {
     var file = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
     var formdata = new FormData;
     formdata.append('file',file);
     const config = {
     onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
        var percentCompleted = Math.round( (progressEvent.loaded * 100) 
         / progressEvent.total );
        console.log(percentCompleted)
         setProgressPercentage(percentCompleted)
    }
};
axios.post("/upload/test", formdata,  config,{
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}}  <progress max="100" value={progressPercentage}></progress>
```

My code may be wrong but I hope you get the Idea